# App just opens and closes after running from android studio on android phone

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, crash

App just opens and closes after running from android studio on android studio.

Following warning is also shown :

The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.

I tried making making the app from a tutorial, the app is compiled successfully but just opens and closes when it is  run on android phone.

build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//add library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE= 1;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
RelativeLayout activity_main;
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_sign_out){
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
              Snackbar.make(activity_main,"You have been signed out.",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              finish();
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Successfully signed in.Welcome !",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        displayChatMessage();
    }
    else {
        Snackbar.make(activity_main,"We couldn't sign you in.Please try again later",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity_main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
            input.setText("");
        }
    });

//check if not sign in then navigate signin page
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()==null)
{
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
  else {
    Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Welcome "+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

//load content
    displayChatMessage();
}

private void displayChatMessage() {
    ListView listOfMessage=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    //Suppose you want to retrieve "chats" in your Firebase DB:
    Query query = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
//The error said the constructor expected FirebaseListOptions - here you create them:
    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
            .build();
    //Finally you pass them to the constructor here:
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            TextView messageUser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

**EDITED**

log error from logcat

```
08-03 02:00:47.736 3199-3199/com.example.hp.chatapp E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
08-03 02:00:47.737 3199-3199/com.example.hp.chatapp E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

Comment: Put your `stacktrace` here

Comment: Log error from your logcat

Comment: @AbnerEscócio JUST added log error .

Comment: @AbnerEscócio edited my answer and added log error from logcat. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Firebase` tool within Android Studio. Select the service you want to integrate, and follow the step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all other setup is correct, the error is self explanatory. You need to add a dependency on Firebase Core in your app gradle file under dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

You might also want to check out the link below for any missing steps.

[Add Firebase to Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: but running app after adding this crashes it